# heroku uncaught reference error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So i've developed my web application, Ready to push live, however testing it on heroku has caused a number of issues. This one so far is one of the biggest.

I have this code at the top of my show page

```
  var api = '<%= @event.link.split('/')[-1] %>';
```

However, In heroku i get a console error that states that api is an uncaught referenceerror. see below.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: api is not defined
```

I've had to change in the production environment vars to make the javascript precompile. (they were not being found and were giving off a 404 error until i did this.

Any ideas/help would be great on how to make it so the api can be used inside the javascript file (its working fine on local)

Sam

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you're calling a *dynamic* value for a static command-chain (JS).

```
// @event won't be present unless there's a request
var api = '<%= @event.link.split('/')[-1] %>';
```

Javascript is static (especially when it's precompiled before running in production). This means that any references inside your JS have to come from objects loaded into the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Because you're calling `@event`, which is a Ruby `@instance_variable`, I'd surmise your JS is simply unable to read it, especially if you're precompiling.

You need to remove the dynamic reference to `@event`:

```
var api = "test";
```

--

If the above works, you'll have to refactor your code so that `@event` is accessible through an HTML element:

```
 var api = $("#event").data("event-link");

 <div id="event" data-event-link="......">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sam, yes it will because the assets are precompiled at runtime in development. In production, they're compiled at push/deploy

Comment: I'll have to try this later after work, Thanks for answering my other question also! Want to try my newest question? haha!